# Como copiar string de um vetor para outro vetor em C?

Tags: c, array, funções

Estou tentando criar um programa que terá uma função chamada `substring` em que o usuário irá colocar a posição do índice de um vetor de origem em que se irá copiar e o tamanho de quantas letras irá copiar deste vetor.

**Exemplo :**

```
vetor_origem = "algoritmo"

substring(0,4) -- > "algo"
```

Ou seja, eu quero que o usuário coloque o tamanho de quanto ele deseja copiar e a partir de uma posição do índice, eu já dei uma olhada em alguns outros lugares, mas não consegui direito reproduzir no código.

Mas para isto, não sei como posso prosseguir. Como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: Mas eu preciso que antes da cópia tenha input do usuário, as outras questões não tem o input do usuário, elas já vem com um valor pré-definido.

Comment: Exemplo testado: https://pastebin.com/vp48Hizz